# WebClient DownloadString is not downloading content exactly same as the web page

Tags: c#, web, webclient

I am trying to use google translate web page as below:

```
string url = String.Format("http://www.google.com/translate_t?hl=en&ie=UTF8&text=Hello&langpair=en|tr");
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
string result = webClient.DownloadString(url);
```

The problem is, when I look at google chrome developer tools, inspect elements, the actual page content is a little different from the downloaded string. I want to get alternate texts from google translate but `webClient.DownloadString(url)` does not download them.

Why are these two different, what can I do to download the web page content as I see on the browser?

[image]

Comment: As always in such case, most likely explanation is those alternate texts are fetched with javascript.

Comment: Look for browser automation instead (like selenium/watin).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is ajax call. Why do not you check out the google api

[image]

Comment: Isn't this api paid? Where can I find this documentation?

Comment: you can examine it here

 [Google Translate APİ](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/translating-text)